# Passing shell script variable to Python script as argument

Tags: python, shell, unix

Am writing shell script which takes argument,

```
while getopts ":i:o:m" opt; do
  case $opt in
    i) a="$OPTARG"
    ;;
    o) b="$OPTARG"
    ;;
    m) c="$OPTARG"
    ;;
    \?) echo "Invalid option -$OPTARG" >&3
    ;;
  esac
done
```

then am adding

```
python filename.py a b c
```

instead value of variable, variable name is sent to the Python program.

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: use `"$a"` instead of `a`

Comment: I thin you just forgot to add the `$`? Use: `python filename.py "$a" "$b" "$c"` ... In shell scripts you need to use a `$` before variables. I also added quotes for safety by the way, otherwise things will break if there's a space in the value ;-)

Comment: and be sure to learn about shell scripting

Comment: Thank you, It worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to get the value of variable in shell use $variable_name.
See the below example

```
root@s:/tmp# cat t.sh
#!/bin/sh
a="test"
b="test2"
c="test3"
python test.py $a $b $c

root@s:/tmp# cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
print  sys.argv[1:]


root@s:/tmp# ./t.sh
['test', 'test2', 'test3']
```

Answer (score -3):

You can access environment variables by name, but you need to export them.

on bash

```
myvariable="something"
export myvariable
```

on python

```
import os
print os.environ["myvariable"]
```